# request.getFile cannot resolve symbol

Tags: grails

I'm trying to submit an image to a specific directory in grails, while searching I found the codes to upload use the following method "getFile" however this method is not recognized and the dependendices or imports are not found, the controller is this one

```
   def uploadImage(){
    def file=request.getFile('image')
    String imageUploadPath=grailsApplication.config.imageUpload.path
    try{
        if(file && !file.empty){
            file.transferTo(new File("${imageUploadPath}/${file.name}"))
            flash.message="your.sucessful.file.upload.message"
        }
        else{
            flash.message="your.unsucessful.file.upload.message"
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        log.error("Your exception message goes here",e)
    }

}
```

I did a search, and this is supposed to be the only way..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "dependencies or import are not found". It's a method on the grails request object that is injected, so you generally don't get autocomplete on it in IDE's. The real question is, what isn't working? What error do you get when you run the code?

Comment: I get the error while running the .getFile is an error detected by grails so I think I only need an specific import or dependencies for the build.gradle

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is the error message?

Comment: "No signature of method: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getFile()" sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using `<g:uploadForm />` for the client side upload, otherwise, you get the wrong facade loaded in the controller.

Comment: I don't think your answer can be applied to REST controllers that do not require `gsp`s